# Creating Android Simulation Application Eg: Electric Circuit App

Tags: android

So am really new with android app developing and i came across the Electric Circuit App and need to know how to create such an app with the workspace that can simulate a connection,

Could someone please direct me in the right direction on where to begin.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite interesting Java - based SimCir simulator for digital circuits, under I think probably MIT license, check. The project page is [here](http://www.d-project.com/simcir/index.html) and there is also a fork of it with many example circuits, [here](http://www.ultrastudio.org/en/Category%3aProject%3aSimCir). The initial versions are not Swing based so may be possible to port with some effort.

Comment: Audrius Thanks ... really interesting i guess just transferring the same ideas on to Android and i have got it

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to learn from examples (learning by doing)

on pages like https://developer.android.com/training/index.html
you will find a lot of information about programming

or you can buy books and read them

The best way is to start with a small app like a calculator to get in touch with Android and Eclipse.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks i have already started on training so am asking how to create such a simulation in android. For instance do you use Gaming Develpment or is it something entirely different

Comment: @LeonardN you can check openFL project, you can develop for android as easy as for Flash Player ..